# Changing the text colour depending on the value on ax.text

Tags: python, colors, bar-chart, seaborn

I am plotting a horizontal bar chart with percentages on, but would like the values > 0 to be colored in green, with the negatives in red.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

clrs = ['b' if (x > 10) else 'gray' for x in data2['BASE VOLUME %']]
ax = sns.barplot(x,y, data=data2, palette=clrs)
ax.set_xlabel('Base Volume',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Color Group',fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)

for i, v in enumerate(data2['BASE VOLUME %']):
    ax.text(0 + 0.01*max(data['BASE VOLUME']), i + len(data2)/50, str("{0:.1f}%".format(v)), color='black', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)

for i, v in enumerate(diff['% Change from last month']):
    ax.text(1.06*max(data['BASE VOLUME']), i + len(data2)/50, str("{0:.1f}%".format(v)), color='red', fontweight='bold',
```

See graph below. The values 21.5%, 10.0% etc need to be in green.

When I try the line `colors = ['r' if (y < 0) else 'g' for y in diff['% Change from last month'].values]`, and change `color='red'` to `color='colors'`

I get the error:
`ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: ('g', 'r', 'g', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r')`
[image: all red]

Comment: `color=colors[i]`. Note that you will need some basic understanding of python when using matplotlib. Reading a tutorial which covers loops and lists would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, was much simpler than expected :)

Answer (score 0):

In the line,

```
for i, v in enumerate(diff['% Change from last month']):
    ax.text(1.06*max(data['BASE VOLUME']), i + len(data2)/50, str("{0:.1f}%".format(v)), color='red', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
```

you could try an if-else statement like

```
for i, v in enumerate(diff['% Change from last month']):
    if v > 0:
        ax.text(1.06*max(data['BASE VOLUME']), i + len(data2)/50, str("{0:.1f}%".format(v)), color='g', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)

    else:
        ax.text(1.06*max(data['BASE VOLUME']), i + len(data2)/50, str("{0:.1f}%".format(v)), color='r', fontweight='bold',
```